# Resize a CSS div box dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if i have one div box with this css content:

```
.box
{
  border-radius: 18px;
  background: blue
  width: 260px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px; 
  top: 5px;
}
```

is it possible to create a second box with only other width, height, left and top with something like a function call with parameters in JS or something else where I only can change this params and dont need define more css boxes by myself?

Comment: So you're wondering if you can create a new element with the same dimensions as .box with javascript? The answer is yes - this question is also tagged with jQuery are you using jQuery as well?

Comment: add another one class f.e <div class="box short-box"></div>, and specify witdth for .short-box { width: , height ...}

Comment: @Robert yes jQuery would also be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/91shfpxm/

```
$(function(){
    var newbox = createBox(200, 300, 100, 50);
    $('body').append(newbox);
});

function createBox(w, h, t, l)
{
    return $('<div class="box"></div>').css('width', w + 'px').css('height', h + 'px').css('left', l).css('top', t);
}
```

Comment: I was about to answer this same thing haha, the only thing I would add is that you don't need to make separate calls to .css http://jsfiddle.net/91shfpxm/2/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will get you started:

```
function newBoxElement(cssClass, position, aWidth, aHeight){

    var markup = '<div class = "'+cssClass+'"></div>';
    $("body").append(markup);
    $('.'+cssClass).css({'position': 'absolute', display: 'block', top: position.top, left: position.left, height: aHeight, width: aWidth, border: '1px solid black'});
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nn3hboon/

Note that the parameter cssClass is a string, position is an object assuming you're using something like $(element).offset(), and width and height are just width and height values you can get from using offsetWidth and offsetHeight on an element.

Comment: I tried this too but the box looks different (like a square) in my code than in your jsfiddle and i don't know why.

Comment: You asked for the height, width, and position to be the same. If you want an identical element just create another <div class = "box"></div> element.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create css classes by creating a style tag in your header as follows:

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .newbox{ color:#f00; font-weight:bold;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

But in you case since you are already have a css class defined and would like to just change it's attributes, you can simply select that class using class selector in jquery and change its attributes on the fly.

```
$(document).find(".box").css("width","200px").css("height","300px").css("background-color","green");
```